# how long will an insertion sort algorithm take to sort a list of 6 elements?

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity, comparison

"In the worst case, assuming each odd comparison takes 2 µs and each even comparison takes 1 µs, how long will an insertion sort algorithm take to sort a list of 6 elements?"

So I have a class where we are taught how to code in Java. We are learning about sorting algorithms like Bubble, Merge, Insertion or Quick sorts and their time complexities. In a quiz, I got this question. The answer to this question was 30 µs. Why is that the answer? (btw the question was just that. No program or description was provided).

Comment: What are "odd"/"even" comparisons?

Comment: Since you were even already given the answer: what did the instructor say when you asked them for an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been too many years since I did any CS like this so I might be completely off but then I'm sure people will comment on the validity of this answer, but this is what I think your professor means happens.
Which if I'm correct seems weird, since one of the comparisons is of the item itself.

**First iteration:** compare 6 with 6, since it's the first item in the list do nothing.
**Second iteration:** compare 5 with 5, but it isn't the first element, compare it with next element to the left. Since 5 < 6 place 5 before 6
**Third iteration:** compare 4 with 4, but it isn't the first element, compare it with next element to the left. Since 4 < 6 move to next item and compare 4 < 5 is true place 4 before 5.
And so on...

```
1. 654321 | 1 ({6,6} = 1)
2. 564321 | 3 ({5,5 = 1}, {5,6 = 2})
3. 456321 | 4 ({4,4 = 1}, {4,6 = 1}, {4,5 = 2})
4. 345621 | 6 ({3,3 = 1}, {3,6 = 2}, {3,5 = 1}, {3,4 = 2})
5. 234561 | 7 ({2,2 = 1}, {2,6 = 1}, {2,5 = 2}, {2,4 = 1}, {2,3 = 2})
6. 123456 | 9 ({1,1 = 1}, {1,6 = 2}, {1,5 = 1}, {1,4 = 2}, {1,3 = 1}, {1,2 = 2})
```

1+3+4+6+7+9 = 30

Comment: Oh thank you very much! How do you know what comparison is even or odd? Do we get that by the index of i or the number of swap?

Comment: I interpreted it as a comparison between 6 and 5 count as uneven and a comparison between 6 and 4 would count as even.

Comment: Oh I see, the sum between them is what is going to determine if the comparison is even or not.

Comment: Who writes insertion sort so that it compares each element with itself? That would just be stupid.

Comment: @KellyBundy agreed, I'm actually hoping I'm wrong with what this professor is looking for. and that I've missed something obvious.